# Replace the item crafted with a tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a map that will come out very soon but I have a problem: When the player crafted a crafting table, it cannot be placed!

And also when he/she crafted it, I would like to replace the crafted block with a crafting table with `CanPlaceOn`.

I think this is used by other maps like The Useless Button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making crafted items usable in adventure mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334767/making-crafted-items-usable-in-adventure-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Create a scoreboard once. It automaticly increments when a player crafts a crafting table:

```
/scoreboard objectives add craftedTable stat.craftItem.minecraft.crafting_table
```

## Method 1:

Put the following command into repeating command block:

```
/give @a[score_craftedTable_min=1] minecraft:crafting_table 1 1 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

**(Have a look at the 1 1!)**

Put a chain command block after it:

```
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_craftedTable_min=1] craftedTable 1
```

Then another one with this command (to remove the old crafting tables):

```
/clear @a minecraft:crafting_table 0
```

The setup should be like that:

[image]

The problem is, that your item has no texture:

[image]

Everything else will work fine!

## Method 2:

(Used in TheUselessButton)

The problems:

- No multiplayer support
- Only one item obtainable
- Bug: You can obtain the item 2 times: One with Can be played On tag and the original (Exists in TheUselessButton)

[image]

Put the following command into **repeating** command block:

```
/testfor @p[score_craftedTable_min=1]
```

Then two **chain** command blocks set on **Conditional**

1.

```
/clear @p minecraft:crafting_table
```

2.

```
/give @p minecraft:crafting_table
```

3.

```
/scoreboard players reset @a[score_craftedTable_min=1] craftedTable
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. `/clear` will just remove the item you provided. It cannot clear items that have no data while preserving items that do.

Comment: Thats right, I fixced it.Now it works! (: